# Shifting the location of tensor3 elements based on an offset vector

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, theano

I have a Theano `tensor3` (i.e., a 3-dimensional array) `x`:

```
[[[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]]

 [[12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23]]]
```

as well as a Theano vector (i.e., a 1-dimensional array) `y`, which we will refer as an "offset" vector, since it specifies the desired offset:

```
[2, 1]
```

I want to shift the location of elements of `x` based on vector `y`, so that the output be as follows (the shift is performed on the second dimension):

```
[[[ a  b  c  d]
  [ e  f  g  h]
  [ 0  1  2  3]]

 [[ i  j  k  l]
  [12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]]]
```

where the `a`, `b`, …, `l` could be any number.

For example, a valid output could be:

```
[[[ 0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  1  2  3]]

 [[ 0  0  0  0]
  [12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]]]
```

Another valid output could be:

```
[[[ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]
  [ 0  1  2  3]]

 [[20 21 22 23]
  [12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]]]
```

---

I am aware of the function [`theano.tensor.roll(x, shift, axis=None)`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.roll), however the `shift` can only take a scalar as input, i.e. it shifts all elements with  the same offset.

E.g., the code:

```
import theano.tensor
from theano import shared
import numpy as np

x = shared(np.arange(24).reshape((2,3,4)))
print('theano.tensor.roll(x, 2, axis=1).eval(): \n{0}'.
      format(theano.tensor.roll(x, 2, axis=1).eval()))
```

outputs:

```
theano.tensor.roll(x, 2, axis=1).eval():
[[[ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]
  [ 0  1  2  3]]

 [[16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23]
  [12 13 14 15]]]
```

which is not what I want.

How can I shift the location of `tensor3` elements based on an offset vector? (note that in the code provided in this example, the `tensor3` is a shared variable for convenience, but in my actual code it will be a symbolic variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any dedicated function for that purpose, so I simply ended up using [`theano.scan`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/loop.html):

```
import theano
import theano.tensor

from theano import shared
import numpy as np

y = shared(np.array([2,1]))
x = shared(np.arange(24).reshape((2,3,4)))
print('x.eval():\n{0}\n'.format(x.eval()))

def shift_and_reverse_row(matrix, y):    
    '''
    Shift and reverse the matrix in the direction of the first dimension (i.e., rows)
    matrix: matrix 
    y: scalar
    '''
    new_matrix = theano.tensor.zeros_like(matrix)
    new_matrix = theano.tensor.set_subtensor(new_matrix[:y,:], matrix[y-1::-1,:])
    return new_matrix

new_x, updates = theano.scan(shift_and_reverse_row, outputs_info=None,
                             sequences=[x, y[::-1]] )
new_x = new_x[:, ::-1, :]
print('new_x.eval(): \n{0}'.format(new_x.eval()))
```

output:

```
x.eval():
[[[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]]

 [[12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23]]]

new_x.eval():
[[[ 0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  1  2  3]]

 [[ 0  0  0  0]
  [12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]]]
```